# Is it possible to draw two scenes to a FXCanvas

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to draw two scenes to an FXCanvas?

Would I need to use 2 sub scenes and then combine them some how?

My original intention was to use subscenes but I'm not really sure how I would go about it considering I need to declare a Scene to the FXCanvas.

```
FxCanvas.setScene(scene); // is needed

fxCanvas.setScene(subscene); // doesn't work
```

Comment: No, an `FXCanvas`, like a `Stage`, displays a single `Scene` at a time. The `Scene` contains a root node, which of course can contain arbitrary child nodes in an arbitrary layout. Most likely, the things you have created as `Scene`s should have been created as `Node`s (or some subclass).

Comment: Is there no way to incorporate subscenes with a FXCanvas?

Ok so i did a bit more reading about sub scenes, am I right in thinking they are simply just another node for you to add to the scene graph?

Comment: Yes, correct. Just add them to the scene graph like any other nodes.